# Why can’t I log in using the token contained in the cookie on mobile?

Tags: reactjs, django, jwt, access-token, refresh-token

The front end uses React and the back end uses Django, each communicates with a server with a different domain in AWS, and the login functions work well on the web

Currently, my functions only work when I am logged in, but when I move to another page, the token contained in the cookie disappears and the login expires

Of course, the login expiration setting is set so that it expires when the refreshtoken expires.

The current problem is that it works well on the web, but when I log in through mobile, the server sends me a refresh token in the header, but maybe it doesn't recognize it, or the login expires right away when I move to another page

The logic is to put only the refresh token in the header as httponly, set samesite=none and secure, and receive the access token as a response upon logging in, store it in a local cookie, and reissue it by refreshing the header every time it expires

Why does the token disappear when changing pages only on mobile devices?

I'm not sure if it's a problem with the token settings coming from the header, or if the problem is that the domain is different on mobile

The token must be retained and you must remain logged in even when logging in with a mobile device.

I think there is a problem with the refresh that comes from the cookie in the header, but it cannot be resolved.